# Facing issue converting JavaScript string to JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to convert javscript string to Object using JSON.Parse

here is the code snippet

```
 var row = '{ "key1": true, "header": "Title A", "Size": 100}';
 $.each(elements, function (i, item) {
    let headerDisplay = '';
    headerDisplay =  this.title;
    row+=',';
     row += '{ "key1": true, "header": "'+headerDisplay+'", "Size": 100}';
    
  });
  var object=JSON.parse(row);
```

Iam getting below error

```
Unexpected token , in JSON at position 177
```

Please let me know what could be issue and how can i convert string to object.

I am expecting output similar to
Expecting output similar to

```
var finalObject = [
    { "key1": true, "header": "Title A", "Size": 100 },
    { "key1": true, "header": "Title1", "Size": 100 },
    { "key1": true, "header": "Title2", "Size": 100 },
    ...
]
```

Comment: it's not valid json. You are attempting to create an array, so you need to wrap the row string with `[]`. Try `var object=JSON.parse("[" + row + "]");`

Comment: @davidhu - Thanks for help. But with this it si giving me array of multiple items. I am expecting only one item with  multiple objects. Please let me know how can we achieve. Updated my question as well with expected output.

Comment: Why are you constructing JSON like this and then parsing it instead of just creating an array directly?

Answer (score 0):

The code in the question shows no reason to involve JSON:

```js
let finalObject = [
    {
        key1: true,
        header: "Title A",
        Size: 100,
    },
];

$.each(elements, (i, item) => {
    finalObject.push({
        key1: true,
        header: item.title,
        Size: 100,
    });
});
```

Comment: With this answer its converting array of multple items. I am looking only one item with multiple objects.

Comment: @AMDI: The expected output you gave in the question is an array.

Comment: yes  its is an array with only one row,but with multiple javascript objects

Comment: @AMDI: Arrays don’t have “rows”. Are you referring to whether it’s displayed as one line or multiple?

Comment: I mean only one item, but with multiple JavaScript objects like mentioned in the question

Comment: @AMDI: That still doesn’t make sense. The question shows an array. Each array element is an object with three properties. That’s what this code produces. If you need something else, please update the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Consider making an Array and then populating the array.

```js
var elements = [{
  title: "Item B"
}, {
  title: "Item C"
}];
var row = [];
row.push(JSON.parse('{ "key1": true, "header": "Title A", "Size": 100 }'));
$.each(elements, function(i, item) {
  row.push({
    key1: true,
    header: item.title,
    Size: 100
  });
});
console.log("Final:", row);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

References:

- https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

Comment: @Twisty-My issue is first creating the array of Json Object.var elements = [{
  title: "Item B"
}, {
  title: "Item C"
}]; creating like this in aloop.Pcould you please explain in detail how we can acheive this in loop.

Comment: @AMDI if `elments` is already an Arrau of Objects, you should not need to do anything. If you're building a new Array and looping over the other array, you can do that too.